# How do you integrate a flask app and a normal cli group?

Tags: flask, click

For example,

```
import click

@click.group()
@click.option('-x', default='xx', help="set x")
@click.option('-y', default='yy', help="set y")
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, **kwargs):
  ctx.obj.update(**kwargs)

@cli.command()
@click.pass_context
def foo(ctx):
  print(ctx.obj['a'])
  print(ctx.obj['b'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  cli(obj={'b':'bar'})
```

Works, or at least let's assume it does (the next one is cp-pastable).  But when I throw flask in the mix:

```
import flask
import click

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.cli.group()
@click.option('-x', default='xx', help="set x")
@click.option('-y', default='yy', help="set y")
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, **kwargs):
  ctx.update(**kwargs)

@cli.command()
@click.pass_context
def foo(ctx):
  print(ctx.obj['a'])
  print(ctx.obj['b'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  cli(obj={'b':'bar'})
```

> TypeError: 'ScriptInfo' object is not subscriptable

I get a type error, and cannot have both a command line w/ context passing and a flask app defined in the same setup.

Is there a way to pass items in through the context object and still have everything managed as a flask app?

Or should I find a work around?